# CentOS 7: xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused xinit: server error

Tags: centos, nvidia, gnu-screen, display, x-server

I am little new to CentOS having issues with starting xserver. This is a intel machine with additional 2x RTX 2080 Ti GPUs for computing. So far I have tried:

[abc@machine ~]$ startx
xauth:  file /home/abc/.serverauth.4623 does not exist
xauth:  /home/abc/.xautha0gT95 not writable, changes will be ignored
xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/abc/.xautha0gT95
xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/abc/.xautha0gT95
xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/abc/.xautha0gT95

(EE)
Fatal server error:
(EE) PAM authentication failed, cannot start X server.
Perhaps you do not have console ownership?
(EE)
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
at http://wiki.x.org
for help.
(EE)
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
xauth:  timeout in locking authority file /home/abc/.xautha0gT95
Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console

---

[abc@machine ~]$ sudo systemctl restart display-manager
[sudo] password for abc:

Note: No error but not X server process is visible in gpu cards.
[abc@machine ~]$ nvidia-smi
Sat Jan 30 12:50:04 2021
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 455.23.04    Driver Version: 455.23.04    CUDA Version: 11.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 208...  Off  | 00000000:18:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 26%   44C    P0    70W / 250W |      0MiB / 11019MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce RTX 208...  Off  | 00000000:3B:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 30%   44C    P0    41W / 250W |      0MiB / 11019MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
[abc@machine ~]$

---

[abc@machine ~]$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf

## nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig

## nvidia-xconfig:  version 455.23.04

Section "ServerLayout"
Identifier     "Layout0"
Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

```
# generated from default
Identifier     "Mouse0"
Driver         "mouse"
Option         "Protocol" "auto"
Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
```

EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

```
# generated from default
Identifier     "Keyboard0"
Driver         "kbd"
```

EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier     "Monitor0"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "Unknown"
Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier     "Device0"
Driver         "nvidia"
VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier     "Screen0"
Device         "Device0"
Monitor        "Monitor0"
DefaultDepth    24
SubSection     "Display"
Depth       24
EndSubSection
EndSection

[abc@machine ~]$

Can someone help in getting it fixed?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please revise your question and use appropriate formatting (in particular block code formatting for file content examples and full console input/output); your post is very difficult to read in its current form.